# Enable "use CUDA" for OpenCV

Tags: cuda, gpu, opencv

In Ubuntu 18.04 (Jetson Nano) I have OpenCV 4.1.1 and CUDA 10.2.89.

However, the command below, in Python, returns `0`:

```
cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
```

which means OpenCV is not using CUDA.

What should I do to enable "use CUDA" in Jetson Nano?